# Logging test gives always the same result regardless of the channels that are defined in the **config** file in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, testing, logging, slack

My test functions are below. I don't have a channel in my **config/logging.php** file like **asdasd** but I do have a channel called **slack_General**. The problem about the test functions is that it gives me the **success** all the time for the both channel name. But It should give me the error for the first function as it supposed to because I don't have a channel called **asdasd**. How can I test the logs are asserted succesfully for the specific channels.

https://github.com/timacdonald/log-fake This is the package I downloaded for the logging testing.

```
public function testSll() {
    Log::swap(new LogFake);
    Log::channel('asdasd')->alert('message');
    Log::channel('asdasd')->assertLogged('alert');
}

public function testSll() {
    Log::swap(new LogFake);
    Log::channel('slack_General')->alert('message');
    Log::channel('slack_General')->assertLogged('alert');
}
```

That is one data from my collection.

```
'slack_General' => [
        'driver' => 'slack',
        'url' => env('NOTIF_GENERAL_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL'),
        'username' => 'xx server',
        'emoji' => ':boom:',
        'level' => 'debug',
    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

This package doesn't assert that this log channel exists in *config/logging.php* ([Check the source code out](https://github.com/timacdonald/log-fake/blob/master/src/LogFake.php)). it just asserts that log message and channel are the same as production code.

Comment: I didn't notice that. How can I check the channel whether it actually exists in **confif/logging.php** file? thanks

Comment: @baruj you can decorate the ** LogFake Class ** and add this feature to it. But if you follow TDD you don't need to check the existence of channel this test case. you should write a separate test case for checking channels.